# Javascript mass minification and concat from a folder

Tags: javascript, minify

Is there some simple way to minify and concatenate bunch of JS files in the same folder + folders in the folder? I only want that, nothing else.

Tried HTML5 Boilerplate ant build script. It is way too complex for this job, though it works somehow. I couldn't figure out how to skip the images optimization part, even when specifying images.default.bypass value in project.properties.

So I need some script to run from a console, so it would minify and concatenate recursively all JS files it can find.

Comment: [Closure Builder](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder)

Comment: There could be problems trying to do that by some completely automated tool, because there can be dependencies between the JavaScript files.  If they're concatenated in the wrong order, things might not work.

Comment: Ben, probably not, since this is a .NET project. I'm also not familiar with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Microsoft solution  http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/
This can minify CSS and JS.  It also has the 'wildcard' option.

Comment: This looks promising, but how do I use this 'wildcard' option? Haven't found anything about it in help.

Comment: You could generate an XML file for ins and outs.  Or you could use this simple GUI that this guy wrote.  http://css.dzone.com/news/user-interface-microsoft-ajax  It will "minify all javascript and css files in a folder and nested folders"

Comment: The GUI was fun, but it doesn't concatenate files, only minifies.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a `Makefile`. Most recent versions of `make` have a built-in wildcard facility like you're asking for. Go with GNU `make` if you don't know anything about this tool, since its very widely available and well-known.

Comment: I have never heard of it, so not sure how well known it is! And given the look of their website, I would be too confident using it

Comment: Well, the `make` utility has been around since the 1970's in various forms and is still the build tool for most of the Linux and BSD world. There are more modern build tools, to be sure, but for simple tasks like yours it's still my tool of choice.